# accessing other google spreadsheet from a remote onedit installable trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script (bound to a sheet) where I put a code for manipulating some oher "remote" sheets.
In this way I can avoid others editors of these sheets to access my code.
All the actions I need to do in these remote sheets are fired by changing the value of a cell in the remote sheet (cell unprotected to the other editors) and with an installable on edit trigger from my account and from my script (in every remote sheet) I can read this value, detect the sheet and execute the action in the remote sheet.

All of this is working fine, but I've found a trouble when I need to access some data in other external sheet.
I've tried to open this external sheet using SpreadsheetApp.openById(Sheet_ID) but it fails saying there is no function/property

Is there any solution for this or another way to do that?

*** Act 19-06-21: it's working fine now. It was my fault using the ID of the sheet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try it with an installable onEdit trigger?

Comment: It is an installable onEdit trigger as I've said

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it works for me:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid);
  tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setValue('Hello World');
}
```

gobj.globals.testsourceid is just a global variable for another spreadsheet id

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I receive an error "can't obtain method or property openById in object SpreadsheetApp". I supose it's because the execution comes from a remote sheet and not from the sheet where the script is.

Comment: I'll try to put an extract... Here in comments or where?

Comment: Post in question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot